# Calling same method recursively from if and else.Getting unexpected output

Tags: java, recursion, methods

Calling same method recursively from if and else.Calee Getting output which is unexpected(As you can see from sysout ).
Expected output:  4

Debugged the code and saw whats happening. But cant understand much. Please help out

```
public class GetSquares {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rectDimension="5X3";
        int noOfSquares=0;
        int noOfSq=getNoofSquares(rectDimension,noOfSquares);
        System.out.println(noOfSq);
    }

    public static  int getNoofSquares(String rectDimension,int noOfSquares){

        int length=Integer.parseInt(rectDimension.split("X")[0]);
        int breadth=Integer.parseInt(rectDimension.split("X")[1]);


        if(length<breadth){
            rectDimension=String.valueOf(breadth-length)+"X"+length;
            ++noOfSquares;
            getNoofSquares(rectDimension,  noOfSquares);
        }else if(length>breadth){
            rectDimension=String.valueOf(length-breadth)+"X"+breadth;
            ++noOfSquares;
            getNoofSquares(rectDimension,  noOfSquares);
        }else  {
            noOfSquares=noOfSquares+1;
            System.out.println(noOfSquares);
            return noOfSquares;
        }

        return noOfSquares;



    }
}
```

Comment: Actual output has two lines: `4` and `1`. I have no idea what you are doing, what you are expecting and what you think is wrong.

Comment: I want to return the largest no of possible squares in agiven rectangle. Ex: rectangle 5X3. It has square 3*3,2*2,1*1,1*1. Total 4 squares.  I got output in else statement in getNoofSquares method (There is a sysout which prints 4) . But when I go to calee method, I am getting 1 as output instead of 4

Answer (score 0):

you are not holding the returned value from method `getNoofSquare()` in recursive call,
get the value like

```
noOfSquares= getNoofSquares(rectDimension,  noOfSquares);
```

Comment: I dont want to hold the output. I just want to increment noOfSquares by one and call the same method

Comment: parameters in a static methods are initialize each time when you call a method. so if you want to increment the noOfSquares variable.. then make it class member. by declaring it static.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that primitive types in Java are passed by value, not by references.

```
public static void increment(int x) {
    x++;
}

public static void main(String... a) {
    int x = 0;
    increment(x);
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

This code will print `0`.

If you want to have an "output parameter", it must be mutable, but `int` isn't. You would have to create a class that is a holder for the integer:

```
public class MutableInteger {

    private int value = 0;

    public void increment() {
        value++;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

}
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
// SOLUTION 1
public class GetSquares {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rectDimension = "5X3";
        MutableInteger noOfSq = new MutableInteger();
        getNoofSquares(rectDimension, noOfSq);
        System.out.println(noOfSq.getValue());
    }

    public static void getNoofSquares(String rectDimension, MutableInteger noOfSquares) {

        int length = Integer.parseInt(rectDimension.split("X")[0]);
        int breadth = Integer.parseInt(rectDimension.split("X")[1]);

        noOfSquares.increment();

        if (length < breadth) {
            rectDimension = String.valueOf(breadth - length) + "X" + length;
            getNoofSquares(rectDimension, noOfSquares);
        } else if (length > breadth) {
            rectDimension = String.valueOf(length - breadth) + "X" + breadth;
            getNoofSquares(rectDimension, noOfSquares);
        }
    }

}
```

Another approach is to just use return value to return the result:

```
// SOLUTION 2
public class GetSquares {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rectDimension = "5X3";
        int noOfSq = getNoofSquares(rectDimension);
        System.out.println(noOfSq);
    }

    public static int getNoofSquares(String rectDimension) {
        int length = Integer.parseInt(rectDimension.split("X")[0]);
        int breadth = Integer.parseInt(rectDimension.split("X")[1]);

        if (length < breadth) {
            rectDimension = String.valueOf(breadth - length) + "X" + length;
            return 1 + getNoofSquares(rectDimension);
        } else if (length > breadth) {
            rectDimension = String.valueOf(length - breadth) + "X" + breadth;
            return 1 + getNoofSquares(rectDimension);
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

}
```

Also, instead of doing string parsing/splitting/building I would recommend to just have two `int` parameters for length and width:

```
// SOLUTION 2 (cleaned)
public class GetSquares {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rectDimension = "5X3";

        int length = Integer.parseInt(rectDimension.split("X")[0]);
        int breadth = Integer.parseInt(rectDimension.split("X")[1]);

        int noOfSq = getNoofSquares(length, breadth);
        System.out.println(noOfSq);
    }

    public static int getNoofSquares(int length, int breadth) {
        if (length < breadth) {
            return 1 + getNoofSquares(breadth - length, length);
        } else if (length > breadth) {
            return 1 + getNoofSquares(length - breadth, breadth);
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java is pass by value. You are incrementing a local variable and you are not doing anything with the value returned from the recursions.

Since you are not doing anyhthing after  but return you could just as well done:

```
public class GetSquares {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rectDimension = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "5X3";
        System.out.println("Number of squares from " + rectDimension 
            + " is " + getNoofSquares(rectDimension));
    }

    public static  int getNoofSquares(String rectDimension){
        String parts[] = rectDimension.split("X");
        int length=Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        int breadth=Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        return getNoofSquares(length, breadth, 0);
    }

    public static  int getNoofSquares(int length, int breadth, int noOfSquares){
        if (length < breadth) {
            return getNoofSquares(breadth-length, length, noOfSquares+1);
        } else if (length > breadth) {
            return getNoofSquares(length-breadth, breadth, noOfSquares+1);
        } else {
            return noOfSquares+1;
        }
    }
}
```

I kept your accumulator so now it's tail recursive. Java don't have TCO yet though.